# From Basic Java Project With Web Service To Deployable Glassfish Artifacts?

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, wsdl, glassfish

I am trying to learn about Web Services, Glassfish, Eclipse, etc. and the way I learn is I like to do things *manually* Instead of playing around with *Dynamic Web Projects* as many of the tutorials online ask you to do. I am starting with a basic Java project and creating the WSDLs, client stubs, etc. *by hand*.

I have (remarkably) come pretty far along. What I have done so far is create a web service class and used *wsgen* to create the WSDL and then used *wsimport* to create client stubs.

The part that I am stuck on is how do I deploy my service to Glassfish? I have been able to do it using Eclipse (right-click, -> Web Services -> Create Web Service) but as I stated above I want to learn how things work under the covers. So let's say I was using nothing but Notepad and a Java command line compiler how would I go from my current Web Service project to something that is *deployable* in Glassfish?

Thanks!

Comment: That's where creating a *Dynamic Web project* comes in handy (in Eclipse). Your Web Service needs to be archived into a WAR file so that it can be deployed to an application server.

Comment: Well I think you have started in the best way. Use an IDE may not be as good as you write it yourself. But an IDE can do the deployment tasks for you, create the WAR, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You find a hell lot of examples on the Apache TomEE website. This one might fit your needs. 
http://openejb.apache.org/examples-trunk/simple-webservice/

You need to package your Webservice and deploy it to the container. There is merely anything happening "under the hood". It's just bred and butter stuff for your IDE. you could also do everything "by hand" (war, http://www.openscope.net/2010/01/25/war-deployment-file-structure/ ; asadmin deploy http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1751/giobi/index.html).

- M